# How to add fingerprint to keystore

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, keystore

I had the following exception while writing to a SSL socket

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
```

It seems like the certificate of the target server is not trusted. I tested my implementation on a windows 7 machine, jdk7 and tomcat7 with no problem. The Exception is thrown on ubuntu 10 LTS with openJDK 6 and tomcat7. I got the sha1 and md5 fingerprint of the sockets target server. Am I right that the certificat of the server I am trying to stream to is not trustet on my ubuntu server? can I can the fingerprint to the tomcats keystore? If so, how do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not the fingerprint that you need to add to your trust store, but the actual certificate.

You can add the server certificate itself or add one of the CA certificates in the chain (if you wish to trust the all the certificates from that CA, not just that particular server).

To find out what the certificate is, you can use OpenSSL:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect your.host.name:443
```

(Replace the host name and 443 by the actual ports you're using.)

The blocks between `--BEGIN/END CERT...--` are the certificates in PEM format. You can check their content using `openssl x509 -text -noout` (and pasting each block there).

Save the certificate you want to import into a plain text file (e.g. `certificate.pem`). You should only import certificates that you trust. There's a certain leap of faith here. (You might want to connect with your browser and check whether the key material matches, for example.)

To import into your truststore use:

```
keytool -importcert -keystore truststore.jks -file certificate.pem
```

(You may need to specify an alias wit `-alias some_name_you_choose`.)

If you want this to affect your default truststore, replace `truststore.jks` with the path to `lib/security/cacerts` in your Java home directory (the default password should be `changeit`).

---

Since the target server seems to come from a well-known CA anyway (and it works with some versions of the JRE), the easiest fix is certainly to update your `cacerts` file manually, taking a copy from a JRE with which it works. After all, as the [JSSE Reference Guide says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Customization):

> IMPORTANT NOTE: The JDK ships with a limited number of trusted root
>   certificates in the /lib/security/cacerts file. As
>   documented in keytool, it is your responsibility to maintain (that is,
>   add/remove) the certificates contained in this file if you use this
>   file as a truststore.
>
> Depending on the certificate configuration of the servers you contact,
>   you may need to add additional root certificate(s). Obtain the needed
>   specific root certificate(s) from the appropriate vendor.

---

It turns out it's certainly a problem with the [certificate chain order](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/28074/11628) (which is incorrect on this site), as shown by [Qualys SSL Labs tester](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/).

Comment: thx for your quick and qualitiv answer, Ill try that. The strange thing is, that the certificate that seems to be not trusted is from verisign. It is trusted in firefox. There has to be a verisign trusted key in the chain... :/ well Ill add it manually like you described and check If the exception still occurs

Comment: Could it have expired or be issued by an older verisign CA in your default trust store? (You can list the content of the trust store using `keytool` too.)

Comment: would you take a look at this output of the openssl command you gave me? http://nopaste.info/5b3b6db2c6.html ; it says that there is a selfsigned certificate in the chain... as far as my understanding goes this cannot be trusted. but the browser seems to trust it. maybe the cacert is not present on my system?

Comment: `self signed certificate in certificate chain` is just there because `openssl` doesn't use any CA certificates by default, it would do that with any server unless you specify a CA list explicitly too. It's not a problem as such. The server isn't configured properly, though (the list is not sorted), which could cause problems (not sure if you can contact the server's admin): http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/28074/11628

Comment: Im confused, which servers certificate chain is not sorted properly? So far, I have to administrate my server. If my own server is not configuered properly, what can I do to configure it? ps. I am using a thawte certificate in my tomcats keystore, dont know if this is relevant

Comment: Not sure which server belongs to you. `https://api.sofort.com/` is not properly configured. (From what I understand, your server is a client in that respect?) If you try to connect to it from Java, it will complain about this problem.

Comment: Yes, https://api.sofort.com/ is the application programming interface of a german online payment provider which I am trying to connect to from my java application. It is hard to believe that the problem is on their site. I am also wondering why the the api is doing fine on my windows machine, but not on the ubuntu server. Can I give you any Information to make sure that a bad configuration of the certificate chain on the companies server is the problem? Is there any other possibilities that I am doing something wrong? If not, Ill kick some asses ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10507/discussion-between-mar-cel-and-bruno)